# two vector same pointer, delete, memory loss

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

https://github.com/gameprogcpp/code/blob/master/Chapter02/Game.cpp

```
std::vector<Actor*> deadActors;
for (auto actor : mActors)
{
    if (actor->GetState() == Actor::EDead)
    {
        deadActors.emplace_back(actor);
    }
}

// Delete dead actors (which removes them from mActors)
for (auto actor : deadActors)
{
    delete actor;
}
```

how is it okay?
when pointers in deadActors are deleted, their is no memory loss in mActors?

Comment: what do you mean with "their is no memory loss in mActors?" ?

Comment: *Delete dead actors (which removes them from mActors)* - that's not what this snippet does.

Comment: The pointers of the deleted actors will stay in `mActors` (and will be dangling pointers).

Comment: I think mActors have pointer that is deleted after for (auto actor : deadActors) loop.

Comment: wohlstad // I mean.. is it okay to have dangling pointers?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I wondered the same. `Actor`s destructor does it.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  Good find, I wouldn't have thought to look there, but it's absolutely cursed solution.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen another round of easy win in clean code vs comments ;)

Comment: `for (auto& actor : mActors) { if (actor && actor->GetState() == Actor::EDead) { deadActors.emplace_back(std::exchange(actor, nullptr)); } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Delete dead actors (which removes them from mActors)
```

This is incorrect; deleting the `Actor`s does not modify the original vector. It only results in dereferencing the pointers to those `Actor`s to be undefined behaviour.

You'd need an additional step removing the pointers from the original vector for this reason.

You could simply iterate through the vector removing the dead elements in one go though:

```
auto writePos = std::find_if(mActor.begin(), mActor.end(), [this](Actor* actor) {return actor->GetState() == Actor::EDead; });
if (writePos != mActor.end())
{
    delete *writePos; // delete first
    // move actors and delete dead ones
    for (auto readPos = writePos + 1, end = mActor.end(); readPos != end; ++readPos)
    {
        if ((**readPos).GetState() == Actor::EDead)
        {
            delete *readPos;
        }
        else
        {
            // move non dead actor
            *writePos = *readPos;
            ++writePos;
        }
    }

    // remove unneeded space from the end
    mActor.erase(writePos, mActor.end());
}
```

Note that this becomes much simpler, if you use an element type for the `mActor` vector that manages the lifetime of the `Actor` object. `std::unique_ptr<Actor>` would do the trick. This way any element erased from the vector automatically results in the deletion of the `Actor` object:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Actor>> actors = ...;

// remove all dead actors moving the remaining actors to the front
auto removeEnd = std::remove_if(actors.begin(), actors.end(), [](std::unique_ptr<Actor> const& actor) { return actor->GetState() == Actor::EDead; });

// remove extra space
std::actors.erase(removeEnd, actors.end());
```

Or with C++20:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Actor>> actors = ...;

std::erase_if(actors.begin(), actors.end(), [](std::unique_ptr<Actor> const& actor) { return actor->GetState() == Actor::EDead; });
```

Comment: thank you. it's chapter 2. there are no dead actors actually. so, the author did not remove the pointers, I guess.